# Store PHP array to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store some PHP arrays that come from a XML API servce into a MYSQL DB, and  clear them on the session is closed or a new search is made

Have any ideea if this can be posible?

My Variables are  `$img[][]`, `$name[]` and `$product[]->type[]->Category; and a unique variable:`$searchID`

My final purpose is to store them into mySQL DB so i can create pagination system

Any advise will be much appreciated..

Comment: If you clear them when the session closes why store them in a db?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles i want to store them into a db so i can use them in a pagination system. ANd i want to clear them to not overloading my db.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I expected I'd skip the db and only store them in session vars. But if I did want to store an array in a database the first thing that comes to mind is to store it as a stringified JSON object.

Comment: Use json_encode or serialize (it's better because dont lose data types).

Answer (score 0):

```
$st=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`img`,`name`,`Category`,`searchID`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$st->execute($img[x][x],$name[x],$product[x]->type[x]->Category,$searchID);
```

? maybe serialize() / json_encode it if its not basic variables